# Linear transformation of an infinitesimal rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation of two random variables

$V=aX+bY$

$W=cX+eY$

or

$\begin{bmatrix}V\\W \end{bmatrix} $$=\begin{bmatrix}a &b \\ c& e\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y \end{bmatrix} $

Consider the infinitesimal rectangle shown in the figure below. The points in this rectangle are mapped into the parallelogram.

[image]

I don't understand how the point $(x+dx,y)$ from the rectangle becomes $(v+a dx,w+c dx)$in the parallelogram.

Comment: Don't let the diagram trick you into thinking that $(x,y)$ is fixed by the linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformation is

$$(v;w)=T(x;y)=(ax+by; cx+ey)$$

i.e, $\mathbf v=\mathbf{ax+by}$ and $\mathbf w=\mathbf{cx+ey}$.

Then, applying the transformation in the vector $(x+dx,y)$:

$$T(x+dx;y)=(a(x+dx)+by;\ c(x+dx)+ey)$$
$$ = (\mathbf{(ax+by)}+adx;\ \mathbf{(cx+ey)}+cdx)=(\mathbf v+adx;\ \mathbf w+cdx) $$

Answer (score 0):

Using matrix multiplication of a $2\times 2$ matrix by a $2\times 1$ column vector,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&e
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x+dx\\y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a(x+dx)+by\\c(x+dx)+ey
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
ax+adx+by\\cx+cdx+ey
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
v+adx\\w+cdx
\end{bmatrix}.
$$